# Bind Angular2 values in SVG linear gradient stop offset?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I want to use bind angular2 values in linear-gradient stop offset but its giving me errors. Can someone tell me how can I bind angular2 values in stop offset of linear-gradient as demonstrated below?

test.component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, ViewEncapsulation, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
selector: 'test-comp',
templateUrl: 'test-component.html',
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() name: string;
@Input() flexScore: number;

protected goodScore: number;
protected dangerScore: number;
protected isComplete: boolean = false;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.goodScore = this.flexScore;
  this.dangerScore = 100 - this.goodScore;
  console.log(this.goodScore + ' ' + this.dangerScore);
  this.isComplete = true;
 }
}
```

test-component.html

```
<div class="individual-athlete-risk">
  <span id="name">{{name}}</span>
  <span id="score">{{flexScore}}</span>
</div>
<svg width="200" height="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient id="testGradient">
          <stop attr.offset="{{goodScore}}%" stop-color="blue"/>
          <stop attr.offset="{{dangerScore}}%" stop-color="red"/>
      </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(/test#testGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="9"/>
</svg>
```

Its giving me errors. I want to add gradient line with dynamic values. Please help.

[image]

@Gaunter I have updated/edited the code what you said, now the errors removed but still it seems that bar/gradient is constant based on the values determined in OnInit() function. I have checked the goodScore and dangerScore values in OnInit they are correct and not uniform. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
      <stop [attr.offset]="goodScore" stop-color="blue"/>
      <stop [attr.offset]="dangerScore" stop-color="red"/>
```

You need either `[attrname]="fieldName"` or `attrname="{{fieldName}}"` to get Angular2 binding.
SVG elements don't have properties, therefore you need to do attribute binding, therefore the additional `attr.` prefix for binding to SVG elements.

Comment: Thanks alot. Exactly, this is what I want

Comment: I have updated the above code the errors removed but gradient line/bar is still constant for every value. Any wild guess?

Comment: Can you create a Plunker? That makes it way easier to investigate. Plunker has an Angular2 TS template.

Comment: Please find the sample/test plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview

Comment: That didn't work. Seems you didn't save. It's only the template code.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/pSkiTKpDeVN4lvcTquiN?p=preview


I don't know whats the issue on chromium its  working but firefox didn't. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Seems to be a timing issue https://plnkr.co/edit/AnfgB8KmQeaksHKMd5Mu?p=preview I set `showRect´ with a `setTimeout` to give Angular2 time to update the properties. If the `<rect>` is added by `*ngIf` afterwards it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks but still this plunker not works on Firefox. It seems that when first value sets after that it doesn't refresh and same value sets for all. Please help!
I changed the first value in array and it sets for all

Comment: The Plunker doesn't run in Firefox :-( I get some zone exception. Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: Any luck on fixing the same value being repeated for all the remaining svgs ? Even i am facing the same issue :(