# Angular svg different instances sharing same defs

Tags: angular, svg

I have an angular component, where I am changing the battery svg status fill by using the def.

```
    <svg #batteryIcon width="95%" height="95%" viewBox="0 0 260 399">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient #batteryLG id="batteryLG" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue" />
            <stop [attr.offset]="value" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="royalblue" />
            <stop [attr.offset]="value" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="royalblue" />
        </linearGradient>

    </defs>
<svg:rect id="rect" fill="url(#batteryLG)" x="-30" y="0" width=25% height="100%" ></svg:rect>
   </svg>
```

This works fine if i have a single instance of the component. If i have multiple components which have different values for "value", all the components show the fill of the first component.

Not sure where I made a mistake

Similar issue : [Updating offsets dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073950/bind-angular2-values-in-svg-linear-gradient-stop-offset)

PS: I actually have a long path for battery icon.. Somehow Stackoverflow isn't accepting a long path. That's the reason i replaced the path with rect. If it was a rect I can change the height of it to achieve what I need :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `linearGradient` elements all have the same `id`, namely `batteryLG`. You could make every `id` unique, allowing each shape to refer to its own gradient. One way to achieve that is to define a `static` counter in the component class, increment it for each instance, and include its value in a `batteryLinearGradientId` property of the component:

```
export class MySvgComponent {
  @Input() value: number;
  private static counter = 0;
  batteryLinearGradientId = "batteryLinearGradient_" + MySvgComponent.counter++;
}
```

You can then bind that property to the `id` in the template, and refer to it in the URL of the rect `fill` attribute:

```
<svg #batteryIcon width="95%" height="95%" viewBox="0 0 260 399">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient [id]="batteryLinearGradientId" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="royalblue" />
            <stop [attr.offset]="value + '%'" stop-color="royalblue" />
            <stop [attr.offset]="value + '%'" stop-color="yellow" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <svg:rect [attr.fill]="'url(#' + batteryLinearGradientId + ')'" x="-30" y="0" width=25% height="100%"></svg:rect>
</svg>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glxpjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-svg.component.html) for a demo. Please note that I modified the definition of the gradient stops, to simplify the demo.

Comment: LOLL.. I ended up doing the same and saw this answer.. Thanks a lot though :)